# Slicing lists containing lists

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list containing 3 lists:

```
V1 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
V2 = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7]
V3 = [8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11]

V = [V1,V2,V3]
```

I would like to slice V so that the indexes 4:7 of V1,V2 and V3 are selected and put into list Z. I tried doing it like this:

```
Z = V[:,4:7]
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: ``V[:,4:7]`` suggests you intended to operate in a numpy ``array``, not a regular ``list``. Is that actually the case?

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `numpy` to get an array that is sliceable in multi-dimension

```
V = np.array([V1, V2, V3])
Z = V[:, 4:7]

# V
[[ 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3]
 [ 4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7]
 [ 8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11]]

# Z
[[1 1 1]
 [5 5 5]
 [9 9 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if it was `numpy.array`

```
V1 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
V2 = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7]
V3 = [8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11]

V = [V1,V2,V3]

import numpy as np

spam = np.array(V)
print(spam[:,4:7])
```

output

```
[[1 1 1]
 [5 5 5]
 [9 9 9]]
```

without `numpy` you can use list comprehension:

```
eggs = [item[4:7] for item in V]
print(eggs)
```

output

```
[[1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 5], [9, 9, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply slice a sublist, but you can iterate over each sublist and slice them one by one:

```py
V1 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
V2 = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7]
V3 = [8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11]

V = [V1, V2, V3]

Z = []

for sublist in V:
    Z.append(sublist[4:7])
```

Or use `numpy` as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Note that the pattern of creating a list and appending to it in a ``for`` loop usually (as in this case) means a list comprehension should be used instead.